# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, java-ee, jdbc

Estoy intentando conectarme a una BBDD de oracle con myBatis y me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
GRAVE: ERROR.nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
### The error may exist in com/iberdrola/persistence/dao/BusquedaDao.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.iberdrola.persistence.dao.BusquedaDao.getResultadosBusqueda
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

La configuración de la BBDD la tengo en el server.xml del tomcat

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" maxIdle="1" maxTotal="20" maxWaitMillis="-1" name="jdbc/nombreBD" password="pass" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//IP:PUERTO/AWDD" username="user"/>
```

No entiendo porque me dice que class es igual a "" y url 'null' cuando como se ve, si tengo esas configuraciones añadidas.

No se que me puede faltar o que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Cualquier info que falte, la añado sin problemas.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor dime que archivos tienes en esta ruta `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost`

Comment: Agregaste el driver JDBC de Oracle en `<TOMCAT_HOME>/lib` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he conseguido!

He añadido el recurso que tenia en server.xml al archivo META-INF/context.xml y ademas he añadido el conector ojdbc7.jar en la ruta local del tomcat /lib